# How do I set up an SSH tunnel to connect to a proxy?

Tags: socks-proxy, ssh-tunnel, squid

I have two machines `S` and `C` that are on a local network. The way to access Internet from any machine on the network is to use a web proxy, Squid3 is being used. So I can log in to the proxy from only one of the machines at a time, and therefore can't access Internet from the other ones simultaneously.

So I set up an SSH tunnel from `C` to `S`. I log in to the web proxy on `S`. I configure my web browser on `C` to use the tunnel as a proxy. However, I am unable to access the Internet from `C`. I do get an error "connection refused" on the terminal where I started the SSH tunnel process.

```
ssh -fND 8080 user@remotehost
```

[image]

My question is: Since `S` is also using a proxy itself, do I need to change any more settings anywhere for SSH tunnel to work?

How does `S` know what to do with the data it receives from `C` through the SSH tunnel?

Edit : I have now done the following : On `S` I installed a squid3 proxy server, and I configured `C` to use the new proxy. This solution works. I dont need the encryption provided by SSH. I want to know this : Is SSH tunneling better than my current solution for any reason other than encryption ? (Please tell me if I should have opened a new question for this).

Comment: @slhck yes that exactly describes my situation. I am using only one ssh command on the client side ssh -fND 8080 user@remotehost. Thanks for the veru useful illustration.

Comment: Not a thing -- I added the image and the command to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command I use:
ssh -g -L192.168.2.1:8190:proxy-server:3128 relay-server

So, I have client machine in local network, a local server, then server that I connect to and finally the proxy server working as HTTP proxy. The proxy and relay server can of course be the same.

I give this command on *local server* after which clients coming via the interface with address 192.168.2.1 can use the proxy. The option -g is needed for the proxy to be open for anyone, ie. outside of the machine creating the tunnel. Using -g is risky, so you *need* to specify the local interface to bind to; you don't want to open the tunnel for whole world.

In your image "Proxy" would be both proxy-server and relay-server, "S" the local server and "C" a client using the tunnel.

Comment: Hi, I am  sorry but on running this command on `S`, I get asked for the root password for the proxy server. Is that the correct behaviour ? I do not have access to the machine running the proxy server.

Comment: The relay-server needs to see the proxy, and have access to it. If the machine "S" can access it, then replace the "relay-server" with S. Also, you can give any login to the "relay-server" part with @: like login@relay-server.

Comment: > Replace the relay server with S
but I thought I was running this command on S ?

Comment: Yup. You can write ssh ... user@localhost and it works.